# Bizarre AR::Base to_yaml serialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to dump some AR models `to_yaml`, to reload in a different context. To do so, I am doing:

```
File.open(file, 'w') { |f| f.print MyModel.all.to_yaml }
```

However, when I view the YAML file, I occasionally see something like the following:

```
- !ruby/object:MyModel
  attributes: *35083880
```

That is, the attributes for one of these models is pointing to those of another. This is incorrect (I've confirmed there are no duplicate records), and causes some issues with my re-ingest process (since it duplicates the ID as well).

What is even more bizarre is that this only happens sometimes. Sometimes the command above will create a perfectly fine YAML file, with no named anchors.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on? I'm using Rails 4.1 with a pretty stock setup (for AR, YAML, etc.).